# I want to deploy k8s 1.26 on ubuntu22.04, but apt install kubelet fails

Tags: apt, dpkg, iptables, kubernetes

**I want to deploy k8s 1.26 on ubuntu22.04, but apt install kubelet fails**

```
$ apt-get install kubelet kubeadm kubectl

You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubelet : Depends: iptables (>= 1.4.21) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
$ apt-get install iptables

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libip6tc2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iptables
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/261 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,613 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 73635 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iptables_1.4.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking iptables (1.4.21-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/iptables_1.4.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/sbin/iptables-apply.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
           Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/iptables_1.4.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this to install kubectl on my ubuntu server, and it worked fine.

`snap install kubectl --classic`

`snap install kubeadm  --classic`

`snap install kuberlet  --classic`

then, checkout the version

`kubectl version --client`

###### ref:

[Install using other package management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-using-other-package-management)

[using native package management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-using-native-package-management)

Comment: Using snap doesn't create the services though:  `systemctl enable kubelet.service` gives 
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file kubelet.service does not exist.`

Comment: @DeanSchulze, kubectl is an executable file, not a service, and the system does not automatically create a related service. You can verify if kubectl has been successfully installed by running `kubectl version`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apt autoremove --purge
apt install iptables
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
```

If these two execute fine thant try again

```
apt-get install kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: can you do sudo apt-get clean and then start over with the previous commands?